# How to do a plot w.r.t. a parameter in matlab which appears in the initial function of a PDE (NLSE)?)

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure, pde

```
f=w.^0.5.*(1-4./(1+4*w.*(X-a).^2))+exp(1i*l*pi)*w.^0.5.*(1-4./(1+4*w.*(X+a).^2));

u(:,1)=f;
figure
plot(X,abs(f))

%--------------------------------------------------------------------------

P=zeros(1,N_Z);
Q=zeros(1,N_Z);
M=zeros(1,N_Z);
H=zeros(1,N_Z);
figure

for n=1:N_Z-1

u(:,n+1)=ifft(fft(u(:,n),N_fx).*exp(-1i*(kx.^2/2)*dZ/2));
u(:,n+1)=exp(1i*dZ*(V+conj(wrev(u(:,n+1))).*u(:,n+1))).*u(:,n+1); 
u(:,n+1)=ifft(fft(u(:,n+1),N_fx).*exp(-1i*(kx.^2/2)*dZ/2));
u(:,n+1)=u(:,n+1).*exp(-(X/(max(X)-1)).^10);
f=u(:,n);
g=conj(wrev(u(:,n)));

P(n)=dX*sum(conj(u(:,n)).*u(:,n));
Q(n)=dX*sum(f.*g);
M(n)=dX*sum(g.*gradient(f,dX)-f.*gradient(g,dX));
H(n)=dX*sum(gradient(f,dX).*gradient(g,dX)-(f.*g).^2);    
end

P(N_Z)=P(N_Z-1);
Q(N_Z)=Q(N_Z-1);
M(N_Z)=M(N_Z-1);
H(N_Z)=H(N_Z-1);

**w_max=5;
dw=0.25;
w=0:dw:w_max;
figure
plot(w,abs(u))**

title('\bf Evolution')
imagesc(Z,X,abs(u))
title('\bf Evolution ')
colorbar
colormap('hot')
xlabel('Z','fontsize',20)
ylabel('X','fontsize',20)
figure
```

My question is that I am trying to plot "P vs w" where w is a parameter in the initial function f. How would I do it? I tried doing it by creating a  series of values for w, but it gives me the error of "Matrix dimension should be matched." I am not sure of introducing values of w as done in the bold part at the end portion.
Please help.

SKG

Comment: The code you provided won't work: you never defined X, dX, w, a etc.
nor wrote any line of comment to explain your code. You should be a little clearer if you wnat to be helped! ;)

Comment: Actually the above is not the complete code, it is just the major part of it. In the actual complete code I have specified values of X, dX, a and all those things; which I didn't included. It runs error-free if 'w' takes on a single value, e.g. w=-1. I am trying to plot abs(u) vs w. My question is how to do it?
Best regards,

Comment: It may run without errors of you define the appropriate variables. I tried defining w an it went on complaining about other missing ones. Besides being not working, it's definitely not minimum.

Comment: Moreover, from my understanding of the code, you are trying to plot a scalar value w vs a functional value |u|...

Comment: Actually, w appears in function 'f'. So, if I specify a single value, which is scalar of course, it runs okay. But now what I want is plotting |u| vs w. So, maybe I need to create a vector for w which I tried doing at the end of the code if you look at around ** ** portion. But it doesn't work giving a error, "Matrix dimension doesn't match."

Comment: It doesn't run at all. If you `clear`  and then paste your code it won't work. And w is not defined in your first line, but is used...

Comment: It is working here. The above code is not complete, so if u try to run it, it will not work for sure. And w is defined later part, see the end portion of the code between those stars ** **. These stars have to be removed while running the code.

Comment: If you intentionally provide non-working code and expect anybody to help  you, you're going to be disappointed (as you can see, nobody still answered your question...) anyways, from what little can be evinced from your code, it looks like you want to plot the result of a simulation which is a [discrete version of a] function of time, space, and some parameters, versus a scalar parameter: this looks a bit nonsensical, and not because of a programming issue...

Comment: It looks like I have solved it. Actually, I just created a vector for w of same dimension as of X, and then created a meshgrid. Thanks anyway.